# Scrapy following links that match a regular expression

Tags: python, regex, expression, scrapy

I am new to using scrapy and regular expressions but after research they seem to be my best solution to extract links I want scrapy to follow. I am trying to follow links from my start URL that only contain a specific state abbreviation but the issue I am having is the URL containing the abbreviation is not uniform they have different lengths, different numbers of leading and trailing characters and for the life of me can't figure out the correct regex to feed scrapy to follow the links I want. Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Sorry for not giving any examples the links look like this

```
/813rents-Inc_Tampa_FL__148254837
/A-Amp-M-Realty_Riverview_FL_92361_037984837
/A-Altieri_Tampa_FL_1257391_877954837
```

Comment: how we will help if we don't know how it looks

Comment: So, do you want to follow links that match `FL` and end with digits, or what is the common pattern of them?

Comment: I'm trying to follow all links that match FL

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass from `CrawlSpider` and use the `allow` option from `SgmlLinkExtractor`, which accepts a regular expression:

```
rules = (
  Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'_FL_'), follow=True),
  Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'...'), callback='parse_item').
)

def parse_item(self, response):
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that seems to be working. Since I am new to both the regular expressions and Scrapy the indentation rules, ( and , sometimes give me misleading errors. I tried your suggestion assuming I was doing something else wrong and it looks like it is working.